# How to set notification's setConentText to a string?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

## I'm trying to take string called reminder via EditText then display it in the notification

```
private static String reminder;
private Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    reminder = text.getText().toString();
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notifications.class);
            PendingIntent pend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 1000, pend);  //set repeating every 24 hours
            }


        }
    });
}

public static String getRem() {
    return reminder;
}
```

- this is the MainActivity class
  http://pastebin.com/YPqqdY7n
- this is the BroadcastReciever class
  http://pastebin.com/ereRAWAN

**the app shows blank notifcation**

sorry for not posting the code directly here because it's a bit complicated to post it here!

Answer (score 0):

Reminder is given a value in onCreate. So if onCreate hasn't been called, you get null as the text.
The best thing to do would be to initialize value directly:

```
 private static String reminder = "Reminder";
```

I'm assuming this is fine, since the value for reminder doesn't change in you activity.

Comment: i don't want to initialize reminder to "Reminder"..i want to initialize reminder to the EditText (which i'm already doing)

Comment: So you want reminder to match what's in the editText; if edit text is changed so is reminder? If that's the case, the reminder will only have a value if the app is running. You also need to put EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);

        reminder = text.getText().toString();

 Inside getReminder. You also need to check if it's null inside your receiver. If it is, then just pass a default value.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it..all i needed to do is to declare the

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);

reminder = text.getText().toString();
```

inside of the onClick method

thanks for everyone who helped.